# PHP script executed in MAC terminal: failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: php, fopen

I have a problem.
I have a PHP script that does some actions and then create a .txt to put some logs into it.

When I run the script using my browser, it works perfectly, creates the txt file (one new is created each time the script is used), writes the logs into it ..

BUT
When I launch the script from the terminal using the command php, then I have the error: 
Warning fopen [...] failed to open stream: Permission denied

The permissions for the folder where I save the logs is 755. The folder is inside /Library/WebServer/Documents/ 
_www is the owner of the folder.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that the directory / folder is accessible to everyone, and that the default file creating permissions of that directory / folder makes the file publicly accessible to the whole system, not just a single user. That sometimes stuffs it up.

If that doesn't work, you could always try put `sudo` in front of your command, followed by a space, so like this:

`$ sudo php whatever here`

You will then be prompted to type your user password.

Comment: Thank you. Indeed the directory was not accessible for everyone. I ended up moving the script in my home folder and it's working well now!

Answer (score 1):

So when you run the script in the browser, the script is being executed by the _www user, which is a hidden user used (presumably) by apache, your web server.

Then when you run the script yourself, it's being run by your user account, which doesn't own the directory the logs are in, and therefore you cannot write to that. You can get around this by running the script as an administrator (sudo php script.php).

---

Alternatively, there's probably something you can do with users and groups to make this work for both your user account and the _www account. Maybe you can add yourself and the _www users to a group, and then set the group as the owner of that directory. I'm not too confident on this part, but it should put you in the right direction if you want a more robust solution than using sudo every time.

Comment: Thank you! I would like to avoid having to run it as an administrator each time so I ended up changing the location of the script to an accessible directory.